# Retrieving a variable number of rows using a table join

Tags: mysql

This is an addition layer of complexity on another question I asked here: [Using GROUP BY and ORDER BY in same MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636318/using-group-by-and-order-by-in-same-mysql-query?noredirect=1#comment103583202_58636318)

Same table structure and problem, except this time imagine that the past_election table is now set up as...

```
| election_ID | Date       | jurisdiction   | Race          | Seats |
|-------------|------------|----------------|---------------|-------|
| 1           | 2016-11-08 | federal        | president     | 1     |
| 2           | 2016-11-08 | state_district | state senator | 2     |
```

(last record has seats set as 2 instead of 1.)

I want to use the Seats number to grab different numbers of records, ordered by the number of votes, for each group. So in this case with the following additional tables...

candidates

```
| Candidate_ID | FirstName | LastName | MiddleName |
|--------------|-----------|----------|------------|
| 1            | Aladdin   | Arabia   | A.         |
| 2            | Long      | Silver   | John       |
| 3            | Thor      | Odinson  | NULL       |
| 4            | Baba      | Yaga     | NULL       |
| 5            | Robin     | Hood     | Locksley   |
| 6            | Sherlock  | Holmes   | J.         |
| 7            | King      | Kong     | Null       |
```

past_elections-candidates

```
| ID | PastElection | Candidate | Votes |
|----|--------------|-----------|-------|
| 1  | 1            | 1         | 200   |
| 2  | 1            | 2         | 100   |
| 3  | 1            | 6         | 50    |
| 4  | 2            | 3         | 75    |
| 5  | 2            | 4         | 25    |
| 6  | 2            | 5         | 150   |
| 7  | 2            | 7         | 100   |
```

I would expect the following output:

```
| election_ID | FirstName | LastName | votes | percent |
|-------------|-----------|----------|-------|---------|
| 1           | Aladdin   | Arabia   | 200   | 0.5714  |
| 2           | Robin     | Hood     | 150   | 0.4286  |
| 2           | King      | Kong     | 100   | 0.2857  |
```

I've tried setting a variable and using that with a LIMIT statement but variables don't work in limits. I've also tried using ROW_NUMBER() (I'm not using MySQL 8.0 so this won't work but I'd be willing to upgrade if it did) or a related workaround like @row_number := IF ... and then filtering based on the row number but nothing has worked.

Last tried query:

```
SELECT pe.election_ID as elec,
       pe.Seats as s,
       pecs.row_num,
       c.FirstName,
       c.LastName,
       pecs.max_votes AS votes,
       pecs.max_votes / pecs.total_votes AS percent
FROM past_elections pe
JOIN `past_elections-candidates` pec ON pec.PastElection = pe.election_ID
JOIN (SELECT PastElection, 
             Candidate,
             @row_num := IF(PastElection = @current_election, @current_election + 1, 1) as row_num,
             MAX(Votes) AS max_votes,
             SUM(Votes) AS total_votes,
             @current_election := PastElection
      FROM `past_elections-candidates`
      GROUP BY PastElection) pecs ON pecs.PastElection = pec.PastElection AND pecs.row_num <= pe.Seats
JOIN candidates c ON c.Candidate_ID = pec.Candidate
```

Comment: Never include '-' in a table/column identifier. It's an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: How is it an "accident waiting to happen?" You'll just get a syntax error if you don't enclose with '`' symbols. Agreed, this is generally good practice but it's the convention I used here. I'll refactor the table name later.

Comment: No. You won't. That's the point.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL 8 regardless ;)

Use ROW_NUMBER to order the past elections:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pastelection ORDER BY votes DESC) as rown 
FROM `past_elections-candidates`
```

Join this to past_elections as a subquery (this is just the bit you're stuck on with the "using pe.seats to vary the number of rows returned per election" and doesn't include the percent bits:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  past_elections pe 
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pastelection ORDER BY votes DESC) as rown 
    FROM `past_elections-candidates`
  ) pecr 
  ON pecr.pastelection = pe.electionid AND
     pecr.rown <= pe.seats
```

If you want to test things out on 8 before you upgrade, loads of the db fiddle sites support v8

ps; percent-y stuff can be done at the same time as the ROW_NUMBER with eg:

```
votes/SUM(votes) OVER(PARTITION BY past_election)
```

eg for election ID 1 that sum will be 200+100+50, giving 200/350 = ~57%

```
SELECT *, votes/SUM(votes) OVER(PARTITION BY past_election) as pcnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pastelection ORDER BY votes DESC) as rown 
FROM `past_elections-candidates`
```

You need to calc it before filtering

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the right fields listed but this is as close as I'll probably get tonight... I've gotten the rows I need but need to join the candidate table to get the name out...

Using Dense_Rank seems to work for this...

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT pec.PastElection,
         c.FirstName,
         c.LastName,
         pec.Votes,
         pecs.totalVotes,
         pe.Seats as s,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PastElection ORDER BY Votes DESC) as rank_votes
  FROM `past_elections-candidates` pec
  JOIN (SELECT PastElection,
               Max(Votes) as maxVotes,
               Sum(Votes) as totalVotes
        FROM `past_elections-candidates`
        GROUP BY PastElection) pecs ON pecs.PastElection = pec.PastElection
  JOIN `past_elections` pe ON pec.PastElection = pe.election_ID
  JOIN candidates c ON c.Candidate_ID = pec.Candidate
) t WHERE rank_votes <= s;
```

This results in

```
| PastElection | FirstName | LastName | Votes | totalVotes | s | rank_votes |
|--------------|-----------|----------|-------|------------|---|------------|
| 1            | Aladdin   | Arabia   | 200   | 350        | 1 | 1          |
| 2            | Robin     | Hood     | 150   | 350        | 2 | 1          |
| 2            | King      | Kong     | 100   | 350        | 2 | 2          |
```

I guess it's just kind of messy having the rank_votes and s columns in the data, but that's honestly fine with me if it gets the results I need.